# Reverse engineer a Entity model based on external Data Service

Tags: sql, wcf, web-services, entity-framework

I am charged with consuming a data from a web service and I would like to reverse engineer their DB model based off of the Service objects it's serving up. Is it possible to do this with Entity Framework? Or maybe something else? Or do I have to do this by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a long shot. You can use [WCF blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) to create data contracts from the WSDL. Then prob. you can use the Data Contract to generate Entities in EF. But I havent try to create Entities using this myself so cant say if that part will work or not.